# mysql trigger insert field in separate table

Tags: mysql, triggers

When a record is inserted into `general`, I want the `regno` to be copied to `conf_regno` in `conf`.

I plan to do this with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, but am unable to get it to work.  My host is running MySQL v 5.5

This is my trigger - which errors out in phpMYadmin:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sharonb9_titles.ins_regno;
CREATE TRIGGER ins_regno AFTER INSERT ON general
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO conf(conf_regno) VALUES(NEW.regno);
    END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE general (
id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
regno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
owner VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
dog VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE conf (
id INT(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
conf_regno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
conf_CH_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
conf_CH_V INT(2) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
conf_GCH_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
conf_SN_Y VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
conf_SN_V INT(2) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: i will say but maybe it help you should change (NEW.regno) to  (ROW.regno) i think :)

Comment: Try taking the `;` away from `END;`? Also, your `DROP TRIGGER` should be before `DELIMITER $$`.

Comment: general is a reserved name in 5.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the delimiter to `$$` but then executing the `DROP TRIGGER` command with a `;` at the end.

Anyway, with only one statement you can skip all the `DELIMITER` and `BEGIN`/`END` stuff anyway:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_regno AFTER INSERT ON general
  FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO conf(conf_regno) VALUES(NEW.regno);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c77ee/1

Comment: Changed name of the table and used miken32's code.Thank you miken32 - worked like a charm.